# remove additional rows with mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql

I have a database that contains the tables.

```
create table student (
    stu_code integer,
    stu_name varchar(32),
    primary key (stu_code)
)
create table teacher (
    tea_code integer not null,
    tea_name varchar(25),
    primary key (tea_code)
)
create table course (
    cor_code integer not null,
    cor_name varchar(32),
    salary float(32),
    unit integer,
    primary key (cor_code)
)
create table term (
    stu_code integer,
    cor_code integer,
    tea_code integer,
    grade decimal(25),
    year integer,
)
```

I've filled three tables manually.

And term Table was generated by a Javascript code :

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="rnd"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function rnd(a,b){
        return Math.floor(Math.random()*(b-a+1))+a;
    }
    for (var i=0;i<600;i++) {
        var stu = rnd(41,49),
        cor     = rnd(10,26),
        tea     = rnd(81,90),
        year    = rnd(1391,1392),
        grade   = rnd(8,20);
        (year==1392)?grade = null:true;
        document.writeln(
            "insert into term (stu_code,cor_code,tea_code,grade,year) values "
            +"(884221"              +stu+","
            +"180"                  +cor+","
            +"15120"                +tea+","
            +grade                  +"," 
            +year
            +");"
            +"<br>"
        );
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My problem is there are additional rows in term Table.

How do I integrate/remove additional rows ?

Is there a way to fill the table with no additional random row?

**/* update : */**

for example :

```
insert into term (s,c,t,g) values (45,16,88,16,91);
insert into term (s,c,t,g) values (45,16,86,10,91);
insert into term (s,c,t,g) values (45,16,87,8,91);
insert into term (s,c,t,g) values (41,15,85,20,91);
insert into term (s,c,t,g) values (41,15,88,17,91);
```

now i want to display :

```
insert into term (s,c,t,g) values (45,16,88,16,91);
insert into term (s,c,t,g) values (41,15,85,20,91);
or 

insert into term (s,c,t,g) values (45,16,88,16,91);
insert into term (s,c,t,g) values (41,15,88,17,91);
or

insert into term (s,c,t,g) values (45,16,86,10,91);
insert into term (s,c,t,g) values (41,15,85,20,91);
or 

insert into term (s,c,t,g) values (45,16,86,10,91);
insert into term (s,c,t,g) values (41,15,88,17,91);
or

insert into term (s,c,t,g) values (45,16,87,8,91);
insert into term (s,c,t,g) values (41,15,85,20,91);
or 

insert into term (s,c,t,g) values (45,16,87,8,91);
insert into term (s,c,t,g) values (41,15,88,17,91);
```

**/*end update */**

**/* update again */**

I could write a code in Sql Server
But this code does not work in Mysql why?
What is the equivalent of this code in Mysql?

```
delete  from  term
where  stu_code in(
select  stu_code
from  term
group  by  stu_code,cod_code,year
having  COUNT(stu_code)>=2
```

**/* end last update */**

please help me to solve this !

thanks :x

Comment: Not sure what you mean by additional random rows. I see from your code that there should be 600 rows of `insert into...`

Comment: Be more specific, what additional rows?

Comment: Sorry I still don't get what you mean after the update.

Comment: @DanielCheng thanks again, A student must choose a course with a teacher
but In my Table term a student chooses a course with more than one teacher
This is an error in my database.
So I want to delete iterations . ok ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming each students can enroll in multiple courses and each student should enroll in only one class of a course.

Since you only have students [41,49] and courses [10,26], there are at most 9 * 17 = 153 combinations.

I would do it this way:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="rnd"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function rnd(a,b){
        return Math.floor(Math.random()*(b-a+1))+a;
    }
    for (var stu = 41; stu <= 49; stu++) {
        for (var cor = 10; cor <= 26; cor++) {
            tea   = rnd(81,90);
            year  = rnd(1391,1392);
            grade = rnd(8,20);
            (year==1392)?grade = null:true;
            document.writeln(
                "insert into term (stu_code,cor_code,tea_code,grade,year) values "
                +"(884221"              +stu+","
                +"180"                  +cor+","
                +"15120"                +tea+","
                +grade                  +"," 
                +year
                +");"
                +"<br>"
            );
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**For your updated part**

Assume you want to keep the record with the smallest value of `year`

```
DELETE a FROM 
    term a JOIN term b 
    ON (a.stu_code = b.stu_code AND a.cod_code = b.cod_code AND a.year > b.year)
```

So what this query does is to find out and delete all the duplicate rows and put the one with bigger `year` on the left.

Comment: thank a lot, your job is good, 
i have other question,
Do you have a better solution with mysql code
for delete rows and update table term ?

Comment: what is t1, t2 !?I get this error in phpmyadmin : #1093 - You can't specify target table 't1' for update in FROM clause

Comment: They are alias to the table `term`. This is something I come up from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html

Comment: Okay I've updated the SQL and tested it on my database by making a copy of your table.

Answer (score 0):

```
delete  from  term
where  stu_code in(
select  stu_code
from  term
group  by  stu_code,cod_code,year
having  COUNT(stu_code)>=2
```

> i think the problem with that query is that it will go and delete all
>   stu_codes and not even have a single copy if stu_code >= 2. U want to
>   keep 1 copy if there are multiple copies.

Comment: Yes, I want to keep 1 copy if there are multiple copies,How do I get it ??I tried it but could not write.
Do you helped me write this query?